# How do I add/update the existing resources in if I use Role in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using Role, RoleBinding in my Kubernetes cluster. My previous version Role configuration is having 4 to 5 resources like (pods, services, deployments, events, endpoints). Now I need to add 2 more resources in the existing role and update the existing application. When i am adding the new resources and updating the helm i am getting following error.

```
error: roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io “ashok-app-role” could not be patched: roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io “ashok-app-role” is forbidden: user “system:serviceaccount:default:ashok-app-sa” (groups=[“system:serviceaccounts” “system:serviceaccounts:default” “system:authenticated”]) is attempting to grant RBAC permissions not currently held:
{APIGroups:[“”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“apps”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“authorization.k8s.io”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“autoscaling”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“networking.k8s.io”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“policy”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“rbac.authorization.k8s.io”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
{APIGroups:[“roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io”], Resources:[“statefulset/autoscaling”], Verbs:[“create” “get” “list” “update” “watch” “patch” “delete”]}
You can run `kubectl replace -f /tmp/kubectl-edit-3458691973.yaml` to try this update again.
```

Comment: The error messages essentially says that you can't grant yourself additional permissions; you need some other entity (for example a cluster administrator) to update the Role for you.

Comment: How can i gave cluster administrator for existing Role object?

Comment: You don't give the Role object anything. When you try to edit the role object it has to be an entity, like the cluster admin that has the rights to do what you are trying to provide for the role. In short whatever you tried would work if you would have done it as cluster admin or as a user that has the rights for that "2 more resources".